# Changing color of pixel using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there a way to change the color of a single pixel in Earth Engine?

Generally, can run I run an algorithm for each pixel in earth engine in a region that analyzes each pixel's time-series and outputs a number that can be used to color each pixel in the region as a result?

Answer (score 1):

- For your first question, I don't think there is a way to change the color of one pixel which is part of a larger image. You can however:

(1) change the colors of all the pixels in an image (e.g. by changing the palette, see the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_visualization) for more info) 
OR

(2) change the value of one pixel in an image, which then will have an effect on the color used to display the image. This can be done like this (https://code.earthengine.google.com/d3a8c42457338c805b65a34fe2503c59):

```
// Take an image from the LS5 collection and select the first band for
// the sake fo this example.
var img = ls5.first().select(0);

// Create a feature collection based on the point geometries drawn.
var points = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry);

// Change the values of the selected pixels to, e.g. to 22
var new_img = img.paint(points, 22).reproject(img.projection());

// Add adjusted image to map.
Map.addLayer(new_img);
Map.centerObject(geometry, 18)
```

- About your second question, the short answer is "yes you can".

This is basically what GEE is designed for, i.e. applying a set of calculations to each pixel in a collection of images and then displaying the results (as a map, graphs etc.). So if you have an image-collection you can do some sort of calculation on each pixel, which in your case would result in one image as output. The values of the pixels of that image can then be displayed by matching pixel values with a certain color (i.e. color palette).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Bert Coerver! Can you please elaborate on Point (2)? How do I change the value for a single pixel in an image? I believe that will get the job done.

Comment: Hello user8091569, I've added an example to point 2, showing how you could change the value of a pixel specified by a geometry.